# Asp.net MVC - Default Values in a Route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have specified the following routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "myRoute1", 
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute(
             "myRoute2", 
             "public/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
              new { controller = "PublicHome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

and would expect the following url to work

```
[http://localhost:58658/public]
```

Since in `myRoute2` for `[/public]` url, I specified the default values for controller and action but this doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: pure guess: put `/` infront of `public/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

Comment: The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of the route declarations, your first (default) route matches the url and searches for  PublicController.

Answer (score 3):

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "myRoute1", 
            "public/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "PublicHome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Install [RouteDebugger](http://nuget.org/packages/RouteDebugger). This will tell you if your route will be hit or not for a given url.

If you are matching multiple routes, the first one will be processed. [RouteDebugger](http://nuget.org/packages/RouteDebugger) will show you all matches. It's up to you to reorder them appropriately.

If ROuteDebugger doesn't work on 404 pages, turn on custom errors. Example:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="err/index">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="err/notfound" />
</customErrors>`
```

Comment: I had public before instead of {public} and still it doesn't work.

Comment: I get the following exception: The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /public/

Comment: Install [RouteDebugger](http://nuget.org/packages/RouteDebugger) to ensure your route is matched. Do you have a controller called "PublicHome" with a GET action named "Index" that has zero mandatory parameters?

Comment: Thats correct I have a controller called "PublicHome" with a Get action index with zero mandatory parameters.

Comment: I have installed  RouteDebugger not sure how is it going to help me because hitting /public returns 404.

Comment: If route debugger doesn't work on build in error pages, turn on custom errors in your web config (make a custom 404 if you like). `<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="err/index">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="err/notfound" />
    </customErrors>`

Comment: getting the following exception: "The controller for path '/public/publichome/index' was not found or does not implement IController."

Comment: I had two routes changing the order of them resolved the issue. I have updated the question with two routes so that the correct answer is  in-sync.

Comment: @haroonxml. I noticed you marked atika as correct answer. My post provided that same answer "If you are matching multiple routes, the first one will be processed".

Comment: That's correct flem, the only reason I marked atika's answer correct is because his reply was more specific and resolved the issue. I have given your answer plus points as well as it was very informative and helped me learn about RouteDebugger but our chat ended up diverting into other areas.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have put curly braces around public in you route, because it's nota parameter.

Comment: I had public before instead of {public} and still it doesn't work.